# add dynamic html parent using wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

I do `$('p').wrap('<div class="paragraph"></div>')` but got 4 `div` wrapping each `p`, how to have just 1 wrapper to wrap every `p`?

Comment: To wrap *every* or to wrap *all* `p`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `.wrapAll()` instead of `.wrap()`.

> [**`.wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/): Wrap an HTML structure around **each** element in the set of matched elements.
>   [**`.wrapAll()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/): Wrap an HTML structure around **all** elements in the set of matched elements.

```
$('p').wrapAll('<div class="paragraph"></div>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6af2v4o/)**